# Service is null in broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, null, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to start a new service on completion of booting of Phone. So I create Broadcast Receiver for that as follows

```
   @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent("com.android.reminder.BootService");

        //mServiceIntent.setAction("com.android.reminder.BootService");
        ComponentName service = context.startService(mServiceIntent);

        if (service==null) {
            // something really wrong here
            Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, Service is found null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Service is not null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and declaration in Manifest File is -

```
     .....
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="com.android.reminder.BootService">
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I found the Toast is "Sorry, Service is found null" and service is not started.....

Please Help me....
Thx in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need

```
 Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
```